# In a stack using nginx-ingress and ingress-dns addons, when I use in browser lamp-dev.com/server, I get not found and /phpmyadmin 503

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

If in the ingress rules I only specify the host to do the forwarding, when editing `/etc/hosts` I relate the ip of minikube with the host as follows: `ip lamp-dev.com`, the problem I want to give these two paths to the host: `lamp-dev.com/server` returns not found and `lamp-dev.com/phpmyadmin` returns 503, reviewing the kubernetes documentation regarding the entry controller I have it identical to the example they use.

- server

```yaml
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    metadata:
      name: apachephp-deployment
      namespace: lamp-dev
      labels:
        app: apache
    spec:
      replicas: 3
      selector:
        matchLabels:
          app: apachephp
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            app: apachephp
        spec:
          containers:
            - name: apachephp
              image: localhost:5000/apachephp:latest
              imagePullPolicy: Always
              env:
                - name: MYSQL_DATABASE
                  valueFrom:
                    secretKeyRef:
                      name: mysql-secret
                      key: MYSQL_DATABASE
                - name: MYSQL_USER
                  valueFrom:
                    secretKeyRef:
                      name: mysql-secret
                      key: MYSQL_USER
                - name: MYSQL_PASSWORD
                  valueFrom:
                    secretKeyRef:
                      name: mysql-secret
                      key: MYSQL_PASSWORD
              ports:
                - containerPort: 80
                  name: apachephp
```

- apache-service

```yaml
    ---
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata:
      name: apachephp-service
      namespace: lamp-dev
    spec:
      selector:
        app: apachephp
      ports:
        - protocol: TCP
          port: 80
          targetPort: 80
          nodePort: 30080
      type: LoadBalancer
```

- phpmyadmin-deployment:

```yaml
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: phpmyadmin
      name: phpmyadmin
      namespace: lamp-dev
    spec:
      progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
      replicas: 1
      revisionHistoryLimit: 10
      selector:
        matchLabels:
          app: phpmyadmin
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            app: phpmyadmin
        spec:
          containers:
          - image: phpmyadmin
            ports:
              - containerPort: 8080
                name: phpmyadmin
            env:
              - name: PMA_HOST
                value: mysql-service
              - name: PMA_PORT
                value: "3306"
              - name: PMA_USER
                valueFrom:
                  secretKeyRef:
                    name: phpmyadmin-secret
                    key: PMA_USER
              - name: PMA_PASSWORD
                valueFrom:
                  secretKeyRef:
                    name: phpmyadmin-secret
                    key: PMA_PASSWORD ######
              - name: MYSQL_PASSWORD
                valueFrom:
                  secretKeyRef:
                    name: mysql-secret
                    key: MYSQL_PASSWORD
              - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
                valueFrom:
                  secretKeyRef:
                    name: mysql-secret
                    key: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
              - name: MYSQL_USER
                valueFrom:
                  secretKeyRef:
                    name: mysql-secret
                    key: MYSQL_USER
            imagePullPolicy: Always
            name: phpmyadmin
            terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
            terminationMessagePolicy: File
          restartPolicy: Always
```

- phpmyadmin-service

```yaml
    ---
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata:
      name: phpmyadmin-service
      namespace: lamp-dev
      labels:
        app: phpmyadmin
    spec:
      selector:
        app: phpmyadmin
      ports:
        - protocol: TCP
          port: 8080
          targetPort: 8080
          nodePort: 30307
      type: NodePort
```

- INGRESS.YAML

```yaml
    apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
    kind: Ingress
    metadata:
      name: ingress
      namespace: lamp-dev
    spec:
      rules:
        - host: lamp-dev.com
          http:
            paths:
              - path: /server
                pathType: Prefix
                backend:
                  service:
                    name: apachephp-service
                    port:
                      number: 80
              - path: /phpmyadmin
                pathType: Prefix
                backend:
                  service:
                    name: phpmyadmin-service
                    port:
                      number: 8080
```

When I describe the ingress the output is

```text
error Default backend: default-http-backend:80 (<error: endpoints > > > "default-http-backend" not found>)
```

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes are you using? How did you provision your cluster? Is it on premise or in cloud?

Comment: kubectl v1.22.3 , minikube v1.24.0 , my cluster is created in minikube ,  3 pods , describing node its using arround cpus: 40 % and 7 of memory .

Comment: Did you enable ingress controller with `minikube addons enable ingress`?

Comment: yes ingress and ingress dns , and added ip and lamp-dev.com in /etc/hosts

Comment: How are you trying to access this service - from VM with minikube, local machine or some other way?

Answer (score 1):

> The problem was i did not define anything for default route = "/" and only
> /server and /phpmyadmin were defined that's why i got default backend not found , if some one can point me more technically, i'll be grateful ,but... for the moment i fixed giving "/" to phpmyadmin "being the default" , and apachephp "/server"

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: lamp-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target:  /
  namespace: lamp-dev
spec:
  rules:
  - host: "lamp-dev.com"
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /server
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: apachephp-service
            port:
              number: 80
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: phpmyadmin-service
            port:
              number: 80
```